# Автоматизация docker с github actions

Tags: развертывание, непрерывная-интеграция, devops, github-actions

Подскажите, есть контейнер собранный через github actions и отправленный в docker-registry на сервер, но что бы развернуть его приходится это делать руками пул и ран, а как это можно автоматизировать и какими средствами, если можно скиньте пример?

Answer (score 1):

Есть прекрасное средство, как `docker-compose`.

Выглядеть это будет примерно так (на машинке где хочешь развернуть):

```
version: '3'

services: 
    rev-proxy:
        image: URL_к_твоему_образу_в_registry
        container_name: имя_контейнера
        restart: always
        ports:
            - '80:80'
            - '443:443'
```

И он сам скачает образ и запустит контейнер на основании параметров в конфиге.